# Multiple left joins to single table

Tags: sql, outer-join

I have a whole bunch of tables:

```
Table1: PersonID, A1, A2, A3, ...

Table2: PersonID, B1, B2, B3, ...

Table3: PersonID, C1, C2, C3, ...

Table4: PersonID, D1, D2, D3, ...

...
```

Table1 is special as it does in fact contain *all* individuals (names and personal information) but all other tables are almost certainly missing rows (a person simply did not participate in that event).

What I would like to do is join all the tables together (by the common PersonID) such that any missing attributes will simply be left blank.  So, of course, I thought to use outer joins.  This is what I tried:

```
SELECT * 

FROM Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5, Table6

LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.PersonID = Table2.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.PersonID = Table3.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 ON Table1.PersonID = Table4.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5 ON Table1.PersonID = Table5.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table6 ON Table1.PersonID = Table6.PersonID
```

All this does is give me a memory overload.  I think I'm somehow taking the Cartesian product of all my tables and it's choking everything up.  Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
SELECT * 

FROM Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4, Table5, Table6

LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.PersonID = Table2.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.PersonID = Table3.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 ON Table1.PersonID = Table4.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5 ON Table1.PersonID = Table5.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table6 ON Table1.PersonID = Table6.PersonID
```

to this:

```
SELECT * 

FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.PersonID = Table2.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.PersonID = Table3.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 ON Table1.PersonID = Table4.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5 ON Table1.PersonID = Table5.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table6 ON Table1.PersonID = Table6.PersonID
```

Yes, yo were taking the Cartesian product of all tables, and then left joining it to the others

Comment: Such a simple thing.... Thanks for the quick response!  Well, it's almost working perfectly now, problem is I'm not getting the same number of rows in the output as I expected.  Table 1 has approximately 1000 rows, so since everything is being left joined to it, the result too should have 1000 rows, but I'm only getting about 900 rows.  It's very possible that there are ~100 people who participated in nothing, but I would think then that every field would just be a NULL.  Is this not the case?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a row that is being omitted.

Comment: I think this new problem is software related.  Libre Base is less than perfect in many ways.  When I count the number of rows directly with a new query, I get the right number.  Very odd.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.PersonID = Table2.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.PersonID = Table3.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table4 ON Table1.PersonID = Table4.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table5 ON Table1.PersonID = Table5.PersonID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table6 ON Table1.PersonID = Table6.PersonID
```

Look at the **[SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)** form more info.

Comment: You guys are crazy quick.  Thanks for the help!